# Adjusting the line spacing of chapter headings in the book/report class

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing

In my report, some chapter headings are long and they come in more than one line. The spacing between them is not aesthetically appealing. I need to reduce that line spacing.
Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The following def is from  `report.cls`  and `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.85}` has been added. Adjust the stretch to your taste. It is probably better to have shorter chapter titles.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.85}
     \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```